# Matplotlib not displaying colors correctly in customized colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am trying to obtain a colorbar like the one shown in figure A)
[A)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8plKF.jpg)

But what I get is what is shown in figure B)
[B)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYqio.jpg)

Saying it better, I can obtain figure A, but the colors in the plot actually come from the colorbar shown in B, even if the colorbar A is displayed.

This is my code:

```
cmap = (mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['#d2fffe', '#88fefd', '#00c6ff', '#1996ff', '#3c41ff', '#3cbc3d', '#a5d71f', '#ffe600', '#ffc300', '#ff7d00', '#ff0000', '#c80000', '#d464c3', '#b5199d', '#840094', '#dcdcdc', '#b4b4b4', '#8c8c8c', '#5a5a5a']).with_extremes(over='black', under='white'))

bounds = [0.2,1,3,5,7,10,15,20,25,30,40,50,60,70,80,100,125,150,175,200]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
    
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12), dpi=120)
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection=cart_proj)
ax.contourf(lons, lats, my_var, levels=19, cmap=cmap, zorder=3, transform=crs.PlateCarree(), alpha=0.85)

cbar = fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm),
    extend='both',
    extendfrac='auto',
    ticks=bounds,
    spacing='uniform')
```

Comment: Did you forget to tell `contourf` that it must use your use your specialized boundary norm?

Comment: ERRATA CORRIGE — Did you forget to tell `contourf` that it must use your specialized boundary norm?

Comment: @gboffi you are right! I don't know how to upvote you sorry, maybe I can't.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm quite happy that you let me know that I was right (sometimes it happens ;-), thank you!